# Computing confidence intervals for population variance from a sample in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, variance, bootstrap, lavaan

Is there a package available for R (on CRAN, github, r-forge, etc.) that computes CIs for the population variance, given a sample of data, 95% CI parameter, etc.?

The `Rmisc` package computes the CIs around the mean, but I'd also like the CIs around the variance.

I found a few papers and an online source that contains the R code necessary to do this, and I've already used that code to roll my own implementation. However, given how large and rich the R package ecosystem is, I'm heavily biased towards not rolling my own solution, particularly when it comes to computing statistics measures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the lavaan package. Here's an example:

```
library(lavaan)
df <- as.data.frame(rnorm(100))
names(df) <- "x"
model <- 'x ~~ x'
fit <- sem(model, data=df, likelihood = "wishart" )
parameterEstimates(fit)
```

Which gives:

```
> parameterEstimates(fit)
   lhs op rhs   est    se     z pvalue ci.lower ci.upper
 1   x ~~   x 0.833 0.118 7.071      0    0.602    1.064
```

Lavaan is on CRAN.
You need

```
likelihood = "wishart"
```

To ensure that Lavaan calculates the variance by dividing by n-1, not n.

Comment: Just FYI, I wasn't the one that downvoted you; still haven't tested this yet.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot the likelihood = wishart bit, I've just edited.

Comment: What assumptions does this solution make? To which problems is it reliably applicable?

Answer (score 6):

The variance is a statistic indeed, but why rely on a package to answer that for you rather than your knowledge of statistics? For instance, you might be interested in *parametric* variance estimation in which you might assume (or test assumptions) of certain distributions in the data you estimate (parametric approach). You can also go for non-parametric variance estimation using the variance of the empirical distribution function (e.g. the sample variance) and just bootstrap the distribution of the statistic. There's no need for a package there, just use the sampling distribution of the sample variance.

Example of bootstrap variance confidence interval:

```
x <- rnorm(100)

## sample variance
var(x) 

## CI
quantile(replicate(10000, var(sample(x, replace=TRUE))), probs=c(0.025, 0.975))
```

Comment: Bootstrapping isn't worth the computational cost in this particular scenario. Thanks for showing how simple it is to do such a thing though, and for providing a more general solution for other use cases.

Comment: @ClaytonStanley Since the small-sample distribution of the variance depends heavily on the distributional form of the data, relying on a distributional assumption may not be worth the computational "saving". (Or to put it another way - "*if you don't care if it's right, you can have it as fast as you like*"). Indeed, since you don't even state a distributional assumption, on what other basis than this sort of approach could the question even be answered? It would require guessing what your assumptions are.

Comment: @Glen_b allow me to introduce the superefficient variance estimator: 1, 95% CI (1-1/n, 1+1/n). There may be some assumptions involved.